# How do you count all unique instances of all words on a page? (Python/Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

[Python/Selenium] How do you count all unique instances of all words on a page?

For example, on this page, I want to create a script that registers all words on the page and then counts how many instances of each word appears. I don't need the full code breakdown, just to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counter` from `collections` module as shown below

```
from collections import Counter

sentence = "For example, on this page, I want to create a script that registers all words on the page and then counts how many instances of each word appears. I don't need the full code breakdown, just to be pointed in the right direction."

word_count = Counter(sentence .split())

print(word_count)
```

which will output:

```
Counter({'the': 3, 'on': 2, 'I': 2, 'to': 2, 'For': 1, 'example,': 1, 'this': 1, 'page,': 1, 'want': 1, 'create': 1, 'a': 1, 'script': 1, 'that': 1, 'registers': 1, 'all': 1, 'words': 1, 'page': 1, 'and': 1, 'then': 1, 'counts': 1, 'how': 1, 'many': 1, 'instances': 1, 'of': 1, 'each': 1, 'word': 1, 'appears.': 1, "don't": 1, 'need': 1, 'full': 1, 'code': 1, 'breakdown,': 1, 'just': 1, 'be': 1, 'pointed': 1, 'in': 1, 'right': 1, 'direction.': 1})
```

If you want you can convert the output further to dictionary by:

```
word_count = dict(Counter(sentence .split()))
print(word_count)
```

which will output

```
{'For': 1, 'example,': 1, 'on': 2, 'this': 1, 'page,': 1, 'I': 2, 'want': 1, 'to': 2, 'create': 1, 'a': 1, 'script': 1, 'that': 1, 'registers': 1, 'all': 1, 'words': 1, 'the': 3, 'page': 1, 'and': 1, 'then': 1, 'counts': 1, 'how': 1, 'many': 1, 'instances': 1, 'of': 1, 'each': 1, 'word': 1, 'appears.': 1, "don't": 1, 'need': 1, 'full': 1, 'code': 1, 'breakdown,': 1, 'just': 1, 'be': 1, 'pointed': 1, 'in': 1, 'right': 1, 'direction.': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can store the whole page in a string variable, then you could use the [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html) package with the FreqDist function, which does exactly the job.

Bye